# K-means clustering on the data frame having only one column

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pandas, k-means

`unsup_df` is a `DataFrame` which has only one column: *review*.

I want to form 2 clusters of the *reviews*. One **positive** and one **negative**.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()  
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(unsup_df)  
num_clusters = 2  
km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)  
km.fit(tfidf_matrix)   
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

The above piece of code is throwing an error:

> ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=2

on the line `km.fit(tfidf_matrix)`

Comment: Is your input transposed? It's saying you passed only one data point but you mean to pass one column

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fit k-means to a single-dimensional text data in Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"corpus": ["I am Sam. Sam-I-am",
                              "That Sam-I-am! That Sam-I-am! I do not like that Sam-I-am",
                              "Do you like green eggs and ham?",
                              "I do not like them, Sam-I-am. I do not like green eggs and ham"]})

X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(df.corpus)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
km.labels_.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `unsup_df` must be in the wrong shape. Otherwise, it should work.

[image]

Comment: it's a data frame.  am I suppose to convert it into list or series ? @Louis

Comment: X should be a list of lists or numpy array. One can use 'df.values'.